Giving explicit induced homomorphism between $\pi_{1}(\mathbb{C}^{*}, 1)$ and itself
This question is related to one of my previous questions.

Consider the map $\pi \colon \mathbb{C}^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{*} \colon z \mapsto \bar{z}^{2}$. Determine the homomorphism $\pi_{*} \colon \pi_{1}(\mathbb{C}^{*}, 1) \rightarrow \pi_{1}(\mathbb{C}^{*}, 1)$.

Note that $\pi_{*} \colon [\gamma] \mapsto [\pi \circ \gamma]$. I've shown that $p$ is a covering map, and I know that the unit circle $S^{1}$ is a deformation retract of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$. Hence $\pi_{1}(\mathbb{C}^{*}, 1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Now a homomorphism $\pi_{*}$ between $\mathbb{Z}$ and itself is of the form $\pi_{*}(x) = nx$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. I know the order of the covering map $\pi$ equals this $n$, but how would I determine it using the definition of the induced map? I know that I should determine where $1$, the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$, is mapped to.

What's your favourite explicit representative for a generator of $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}^\ast,1)$?

$\gamma(t) = e^{2\pi it}$! If I compute $\pi \circ \gamma$ I get a loop that goes around the origin twice. So $\pi_{*}(1) = 2$, correct?

Does the conjugate have any impact on the answer?

@Adayah Yes, the loop that goes around the origin twice does so in the clockwise direction (rather than counter-clockwise if we were to omit conjugation)?

$-2$, since you're conjugating.

@NaïmFavier Aah ok, thanks!
